# Typescript arrow function parantheses in filter method

Tags: javascript, typescript, filter

Imagine I have an array containing movie objects such that

```
    const movies: Movie[] = [ movie1, movie2, movie3, movie4 ];
```

I want to select a movie, for instance I have chosen movie2, then I want movie2 to be removed.
The following code works, Imagine m is the selected movie:

```
    movies = movies.filter( m => m !== movie );
```

I want to understand how the arrow function works and tried the following code but it did not work.

```
    movies = movies.filter( m => {
                   m !== movie;
                });
```

What is the difference between those two codes?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is, that the short-hand version implicitly returns the result. The long version from you is missing the `return` statements, like:

```
movies = movies.filter( m => {
 return m !== movie;
});
```